# How can I setup a reaction collector that fetches messages after restart?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How am I able to setup a reaction collector cause currently i have one and it only works till i restart my bot then the reactions don't work anymore how can i make it so I run the command the embed pops up and even if i restart my bot if someone reacts to that embed it runs the code i want it to run?

For example I run .appeal and the embed pops up with the reactions and it works fine but when i restart my bot the reactions still work and it runs just fine.

```
    message.delete();

    if (message.guild.id === botconfig["bot_setup"].main_guild_id) {
        return;
    }

    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send('Invalid permissions.').then(msg => message.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error)

    let discorde = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "discord")
    let fiveme = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "fivem")
    const emoji1 = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "check2")
    const emoji2 = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "investigating")
    const emoji3 = bot.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "x2")

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
        .setTitle('Start Your Ban Appeal Here')
        .setDescription('**So, you got banned from OSRP **')
        .addField('\u200b', '**Ban Appeal Requirements:** \n- Must include as much detail as possible (the more the better). \n- Must include any photo or video evidence to support your appeal.\n- No response = no appeal and you must wait out your ban sentence.\n- Duplicate appeals will be ignored and your ban may be extended.')
        .addField('\u200b', `**To appeal your ban please type below to what corresponds to the following questions.**`)
        .addField('\u200b', `• If you're banned from the **Discord Server** react with ${discorde}\n\n• If you're banned from the **FiveM Server** react with ${fiveme}`)
        .addField('\u200b', '**All appeals are logged and monitored by OSRP High Command.** All troll submissions will be automatically deleted and extend your ban.')
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
        .setFooter("\u3000".repeat(10) + ` `)

    let questions = {
        firstQuestion: ["Call-sign and Name (or Name if non LEO)", "Please type your call-sign and Name or your name if you were not an LEO"],
        secondQuestion: ["What was the name of the person that banned you?", "Please type the name and call-sign of the offender"],
        thirdQuestion: ["What was the ban reason?", "Please type your ban reason exactly how it was submitted"],
        fourthQuestion: ["Why do you think you should be unbanned?", "Include as much details as you can to ensure we understand every little bit while investigating."],
        fifthQuestion: ["Evidence:", "Include as much evidence the more the better. LINKS ONLY"]
    }

    // Use a promise to wait for the question to reach Discord first
    message.channel.send(embed).then((question) => {
        // Have our bot guide the user by reacting with the correct reactions
        question.react(discorde);
        question.react(fiveme);

        // Set a filter to ONLY grab those reactions & discard the reactions from the bot
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ["discord", "fivem"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;
        };

        // Create the collector
        const collector = question.createReactionCollector(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 15000
        });

        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
            if (reason === 'time') {
            } else {
                // Grab the first reaction in the array
                let userReaction = collected.array()[0];
                // Grab the name of the reaction (which is the emoji itself)
                let emoji = userReaction._emoji.name;

                // DISCORD \\ // DISCORD \\ // DISCORD \\
                // DISCORD \\ // DISCORD \\ // DISCORD \\
                // DISCORD \\ // DISCORD \\ // DISCORD \\
                if (emoji === "discord") {
                    
                    message.channel.send("Your **Ban Appeal** has been sent in prviate DM, type `cancel` to close your **Ban Appeal**.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                    let starterEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle('Discord Ban Appeal')
                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                        .setDescription('Proceed with your Ban Appeal.')
                        .addField('Ban Appeal Requirements:', '- Must include as much detail as possible (the more the better). \n- Must include any photo or video evidence to support your appeal.\n- No response = no appeal and you must wait out your ban sentence.\n- Duplicate appeals will be ignored and your ban may be extended.')
                        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
                        .setFooter("\u3000".repeat(10) + ` `)
                    message.author.send(starterEmbed)
                    let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                        .setTitle(`${questions.firstQuestion[0]}`)
                        .setDescription(`${questions.firstQuestion[1]}`)
                    message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                        const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                            time: 5 * 60000,
                            max: 1
                        }).then(messages => {
                            let msg1 = messages.first().content
                            if (msg1.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                            // SECOND QUESTION \\
                            // SECOND QUESTION \\
                            // SECOND QUESTION \\
                            let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                .setTitle(`${questions.secondQuestion[0]}`)
                                .setDescription(`${questions.secondQuestion[1]}`)
                            message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                    time: 5 * 60000,
                                    max: 1
                                }).then(messages => {
                                    let msg2 = messages.first().content
                                    if (msg2.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                    // THIRD QUESTION \\
                                    // THIRD QUESTION \\
                                    // THIRD QUESTION \\
                                    let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                        .setTitle(`${questions.thirdQuestion[0]}`)
                                        .setDescription(`${questions.thirdQuestion[1]}`)
                                    message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                        const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                            time: 5 * 60000,
                                            max: 1
                                        }).then(messages => {
                                            let msg3 = messages.first().content
                                            if (msg3.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                            // FOURTH QUESTION \\
                                            // FOURTH QUESTION \\
                                            // FOURTH QUESTION \\
                                            let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                .setTitle(`${questions.fourthQuestion[0]}`)
                                                .setDescription(`${questions.fourthQuestion[1]}`)
                                            message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                                const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                                msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                                    time: 5 * 60000,
                                                    max: 1
                                                }).then(messages => {
                                                    let msg4 = messages.first().content
                                                    if (msg4.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                                    // FIFTH QUESTION \\
                                                    // FIFTH QUESTION \\
                                                    // FIFTH QUESTION \\
                                                    let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                        .setTitle(`${questions.fifthQuestion[0]}`)
                                                        .setDescription(`${questions.fifthQuestion[1]}`)
                                                    message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                                        const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                                        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                                            time: 5 * 60000,
                                                            max: 1
                                                        }).then(messages => {
                                                            let msg5 = messages.first().content
                                                            if (msg5.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                                            let submission = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                                .setTitle('Your Ban Appeal Has Been Sent')
                                                                .setDescription(`**We have recieved your ban appeal and are currently reviewing it.**\nYou will be notified if the Ban Appeal has been accepted via prviate DM\n\n**Name:** ${msg1}\n\n**Banned By:** ${msg2}\n\n**Ban Reason:** ${msg3}`)
                                                                .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
                                                            message.author.send(submission).then(async msg => {
                                                                let logEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                    .setTitle(`Ban Appeal Submission`)
                                                                    .setDescription(`A new \`Discord\` Ban Appeal has been submitted by ${message.author}\n\n**Name:** ${msg1}\n\n**Banned By:** ${msg2}\n\n**Ban Reason:** ${msg3}\n\n**Why should you be unbanned?** ${msg4}\n\n**Evidence:** ${msg5}`)
                                                                    .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                                    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
                                                                await bot.channels.cache.get(botcon["channel_setup"].underReviewChannel).send(`${emoji2} \`.accept appeal discord <@${message.author.id}>\` or \`.deny appeal discord <@${message.author.id}>\``)
                                                                await bot.channels.cache.get(botcon["channel_setup"].underReviewChannel).send(logEmbed);
                                                                //await bot.channels.cache.get(botcon["channel_setup"].underReviewChannel).send(`**${questions.firstQuestion[0]}**\n${msg1}\n**${questions.secondQuestion[0]}**\n${msg2}\n**${questions.thirdQuestion[0]}**\n${msg3}`)
                                                            })
                                                        })
                                                    })
                                                })
                                            })
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                    // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\
                    // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\ 
                    // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\
                    // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\ // FIVEM \\
                } else if (emoji === "fivem") {
                    message.reactions.forEach(r => r.remove(message.author))
                    message.channel.send("Your **Ban Appeal** has been sent in prviate DM, type `cancel` to close your **Ban Appeal**.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                    let starterEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle('Non-Discord Ban Appeal')
                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                        .setDescription('Proceed with your Ban Appeal.')
                        .addField('Ban Appeal Requirements:', '- Must include as much detail as possible (the more the better). \n- Must include any photo or video evidence to support your appeal.\n- No response = no appeal and you must wait out your ban sentence.\n- Duplicate appeals will be ignored and your ban may be extended.')
                        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
                        .setFooter("\u3000".repeat(10) + ` `)
                    message.author.send(starterEmbed)
                    let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                        .setTitle(`${questions.firstQuestion[0]}`)
                        .setDescription(`${questions.firstQuestion[1]}`)
                    message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                        const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                            time: 5 * 60000,
                            max: 1
                        }).then(messages => {
                            let msg1 = messages.first().content
                            if (msg1.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                            // SECOND QUESTION \\
                            // SECOND QUESTION \\
                            // SECOND QUESTION \\
                            let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                .setTitle(`${questions.secondQuestion[0]}`)
                                .setDescription(`${questions.secondQuestion[1]}`)
                            message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                    time: 5 * 60000,
                                    max: 1
                                }).then(messages => {
                                    let msg2 = messages.first().content
                                    if (msg2.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                    // THIRD QUESTION \\
                                    // THIRD QUESTION \\
                                    // THIRD QUESTION \\
                                    let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                        .setTitle(`${questions.thirdQuestion[0]}`)
                                        .setDescription(`${questions.thirdQuestion[1]}`)
                                    message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                        const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                            time: 5 * 60000,
                                            max: 1
                                        }).then(messages => {
                                            let msg3 = messages.first().content
                                            if (msg3.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                            // FOURTH QUESTION \\
                                            // FOURTH QUESTION \\
                                            // FOURTH QUESTION \\
                                            let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                .setTitle(`${questions.fourthQuestion[0]}`)
                                                .setDescription(`${questions.fourthQuestion[1]}`)
                                            message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                                const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                                msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                                    time: 5 * 60000,
                                                    max: 1
                                                }).then(messages => {
                                                    let msg4 = messages.first().content
                                                    if (msg4.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                                    // FIFTH QUESTION \\
                                                    // FIFTH QUESTION \\
                                                    // FIFTH QUESTION \\
                                                    let questionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                        .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                        .setTitle(`${questions.fifthQuestion[0]}`)
                                                        .setDescription(`${questions.fifthQuestion[1]}`)
                                                    message.author.send(questionEmbed).then(msg => {
                                                        const filter1 = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
                                                        msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter1, {
                                                            time: 5 * 60000,
                                                            max: 1
                                                        }).then(messages => {
                                                            let msg5 = messages.first().content
                                                            if (msg5.toLowerCase() === "cancel") return message.author.send("You've **CANCELLED** your Ban Appeal.").then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 8000 })).catch(console.error);
                                                            let submission = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                                .setTitle('Your Ban Appeal Has Been Sent')
                                                                .setDescription(`**We have recieved your report and are currently reviewing it.**\nYou will be notified if the Ban Appeal has been accepted via prviate DM\n\n**Name:** ${msg1}\n\n**Banned By:** ${msg2}\n\n**Ban Reason:** ${msg3}`)
                                                                .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
                                                            message.author.send(submission).then(async msg => {
                                                                let logEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                                                    .setTitle(`Ban Appeal Submission`)
                                                                    .setDescription(`A new \`FiveM\` Ban Appeal has been submitted by ${message.author}\n\n**Name:** ${msg1}\n\n**Banned By:** ${msg2}\n\n**Ban Reason:** ${msg3}\n\n**Why should you be unbanned?** ${msg4}\n\n**Evidence:** ${msg5}`)
                                                                    .setColor(botconfig["bot_setup"].main_embed_color)
                                                                    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/TMjV3an.png')
                                                                await bot.channels.cache.get(botcon["channel_setup"].underReviewChannel).send(`${emoji2} \`.accept appeal fivem <@${message.author.id}>\` or \`.deny appeal fivem <@${message.author.id}>\``)
                                                                await bot.channels.cache.get(botcon["channel_setup"].underReviewChannel).send(logEmbed);
                                                                //await bot.channels.cache.get(botcon["channel_setup"].underReviewChannel).send(`**${questions.firstQuestion[0]}**\n${msg1}\n**${questions.secondQuestion[0]}**\n${msg2}\n**${questions.thirdQuestion[0]}**\n${msg3}`)
                                                            })
                                                        })
                                                    })
                                                })
                                            })
                                        })
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to set up either local or server database for that and store the message ID to fetch the reactions, if you want me to explain either both or any of the database(local or server) just reply me and I'll post it as answer.

Comment: There is also an another way that you start collecting reactions whenever bot starts like adding it on onMessage or on onReady events.